# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This is my sql code, and everytime I execute it on command, it is giving me an error, can anyone tell me what am I missing here? It is giving me 
"Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" error. Any help would be awesome.

```
Create table course (course_id varchar(8), title varchar(50), dept_name varchar(20), credits numeric(2,0) check (credits > 0), primary key (course_id), foreign key (dept_name) references department on delete set null );
```

This is the reference table:

```
create table department
    (dept_name      varchar(20), 
     building       varchar(15), 
     budget             numeric(12,2) check (budget > 0),
     primary key (dept_name)
    );
```

Comment: Hint: `references table_name(column_name)`. Please read the docs.

Comment: not working! Same error

Comment: Please adjust your statement. And also post the CREATE statement for the referenced table. The referenced column must be of the same data type and there should be a unique index on it.

Comment: Well - it works for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mCkvwMmYpA2Ax3bihaNNmT/0

Comment: Check all the conditions here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html have been met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation:

> [Foreign Keys](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/)
>
> ...
>
> ```
> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>     [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
>     REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
>     [ON DELETE reference_option]
>     [ON UPDATE reference_option]
>
> reference_option:
>     RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT
> ```
>
> ...

Example:

```sql
create table if not exists course (
  course_id varchar(8),
  title varchar(50),
  dept_name varchar(20),
  credits numeric(2,0) check (credits > 0),
  primary key (course_id),
  foreign key (dept_name)
  -- references department on delete set null
  references department (dept_name) on delete set null
);
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5656a1dd3325d5dc5fc09153c1095c4e).